# Wordpress as sub site on Azure Umbraco parent website

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, azure

So I have had some success getting a Wordpress website running as a child of an umbraco parent.

I created a Wordpress site, using Azure and then copied that site to a child /blog dir successfully using this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webapps/archive/2013/02/13/hosting-wordpress-in-a-subfolder-of-your-windows-azure-web-site.aspx

You can see my success here: http://littlenomads.azurewebsites.net/blog/

Part of the solution so far was to change the Umbraco web.config to ignore the blog directory: following this SO answer: PHP configuration on .NET server - URL redirect

So this means if the Wordpress blog is loading the MySQL database connection is working.

But when I try and login to wp-admin, the website spins for a while and then I am getting a 502 error which means Azure is crashing waiting for a long running request I believe.

I have tried debugging following this guide: http://ruslany.net/2013/01/php-troubleshooting-in-windows-azure-web-sites/

I am seeing failed request errors for wp-login.php but this does give me any direction. I am not seeing any PHP errors. http://littlenomads.azurewebsites.net/blog/wp-login.php

I am just not sure what the issue is and have no debugging direction at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by changing directions and hosting the Wordpress website on its on hosting on GoDaddy.

Wordpress setup and hosing on Azure is very easy and you can even using blob storage for uploading media with a Wordpress plugin for Azure but trying to migrate a pretty large Wordpress website and all media to Azure, especially trying to use Blob storage for existing media uploads, is really way too complex.

I am just using a subdomain pointing to a new Managed Wordpress hosting package on GoDaddy with the primary website on Azure and along with some 301 Permanent redirects for existing blog articles and maintaining SEO integrity.